# MySQL client not reading ~/.my.cnf

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I have a server running MySQL 5.7.42 on Ubuntu Linux. I have a config file in `~/.my.cnf` containing login info to connect to it from a shell on the same server:

```ini
[client]
host     = localhost
user     = root
password = myPassword
```

The MySQL server is set to read from the default locations, which includes `~/.my.cnf`:

```
mysqld --help --verbose 2>1 | grep "my.cnf"
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

and the client is set to do the same:

```
mysql --help --verbose 2>1 | grep "my.cnf"
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

`/etc/my.cnf` doesn't exist, `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` contains only `[mysql]`, and there are no `client` sections in anything in `/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d` or `/etc/mysql/conf.d`.

But when I run `mysql`, it fails, saying:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

but if I run `mysql --defaults-file=/.my.cnf`, it connects successfully, telling me:

- the file is readable by the user I'm running the command as
- it is valid
- the credentials work.

I have the same style config file, in the same place, with the same ownership and permissions on several other servers and they all work fine.

Why isn't MySQL reading my config file?

Comment: Neither of these is true. Option files [are supported](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html), and the same docs say that `[client]` is the section name for all user mysql utilities, including things like `mysqldump`, whereas `[mysql]` only applies to the `mysql` client. `mysql_config_editor` is a good pointer though.